# Instantiate a property from viewModel within foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

I am iterating over an object with a knockout's `foreach`. Inside this foreach I render a table, and each table has a dropdown.

I need the value of the select, however the `ko.observable()` is not working within the foreach, because it sets each select value simultaneously. I need the individual select value of each field, not set each select to the same value.

Is there a solution to this?

```html
<!--ko foreach: {data: thing, as: 'blah'}-->
<div data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(blah)"></div>
<select data-bind="options: $root.countries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: $root.selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'Choose..'"></select>
<br/>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.sendMe, enable: $root.selectedChoice" Value="Click Me"/>
<!--/ko-->
```

[This is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8k95s20/3/) that demonstrates with a simple example.

Comment: You'd need a `selectedChoice` member of the `thing` object.

Comment: No,l it's still changing all of the values at the same time, even within the object being looped over.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple dropdowns, you're going to need multiple observables to store the selected value if you want to save individual selections. For example:

```js
var CountryModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};

var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.things = ko.observableArray([
        { blarg: 'blarg', selectedChoice: ko.observable() }, 
        { means: 'means', selectedChoice: ko.observable() }, 
        { yes: 'yes', selectedChoice: ko.observable() }
    ]);

    self.countries = ko.observableArray([
     new CountryModel({ id: "1", name: "Russia" }),
     new CountryModel({ id: "2", name: "Qatar" })
    ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!--ko foreach: {data: things, as: 'thing'}-->
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(thing)"></div>
<select data-bind="options: $root.countries,
                   optionsText: 'name', 
                   optionsValue: 'id', 
                   value: selectedChoice,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose..'">        
</select>
<hr>
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: Ok, this still doesn't work. You're putting the observables on the wrong array, and it's still selecting all selects at the same time.

Comment: How "*doesn't [it] work*"? The snippet runs and makes sense, does it not? Why is that array "*wrong*"? Which is the right array? What does "*it's still selecting all selects at the same time*" mean?

Comment: It's working in this example, not on my code, which would take pages to upload. Sorry man, this is a great solution for this example, but it just isn't working in my code, not exactly sure why

Comment: Ah yes, it can be hard to make a repro that's close enough so the solutions also translate back. It *is* required though before others here can help, since we don't have access to the full code. I'd suggest making a new SO question with more details explaining how it's different from this question and how my answer here didn't help.